# How to insert the file name to the start and the end of a SQL file by a powershell script

Tags: powershell

I just began to learn powershell script and I have a problem that I cannot figure out. I have a lot of .sql files. I need to insert its file name to the beginning of the file (After USE statement) and the end of the file (before the last END statement). Is there anybody knowing how to do this?

Thanks so much

Regards

Comment: is the filename just a comment in the sql file?  what is it being used for?  the answer will determine my answer

Comment: Perhaps a snippet of your code might help

Comment: Actually, I want to insert a insert SQL statement to the beginning of the file and the end of the file. Only the file name is a variable and different among different files. All the other sql statements are the same and can be hard coded. Hopefully it helps

Comment: The problem I think is that I want to add the same thing (except the file name) to hundreds of sql files and only the file name is different. I do not want to add it manually and want to use a script to add it

Comment: Please edit your question and give a practical example of what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
There are a few ways to do that.
Here is the one I would use:
1.  Load up a list of your files using get-item
2.  loop through those files 
3.  for each file, load the sql file into a variable using get-content: $d = get-content -path $yourfilename
4.  then add your data at the beginning and end
5.  $beg = @'
stuff at the beginning
'@
6.  $end = @'
stuff at the end
'@
7.  $d = $beg + $d + $end
8.  use set-content to write the file back
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this. Far to be fool proof, needs checking and stuff, can probably be written in a much more elegant way, but gives you the overall idea.

```
param (
    [string] $testFile = "testfile.sql",
    [string] $result = "testfilemodified.sql"
)

$fileContent = Get-Content $testFile
$lineCount = $fileContent.Count
$count = $lineCount

$fileContent | %{

    $line = $_
    $count--

    $line | Out-File $result -Append

    if ($line.Contains("use"))
        { "-- $testFile" | Out-File $result -Append; }

    if ($count -eq 1)
        {  "-- $testFile" | Out-File $result -Append; }
}
```